# Is it possible to have "two" sets of tags?

Tags: custom-post-types, tags

I have several Custom Category Taxonomies but what I am wondering is, if it's possible to have a second set of "tags"?

I am using my tags for a very specific purpose (the naming of cities) so I don't want to mix up that with what I need for another set of tags.

Sure, I can create another Category Taxonomy but the quantity of items means that a "tag" environment might be better...

Thanks

Comment: Custom taxonomies don't have to be hierarchical like categories, they can be non-hierarchical like tags, in fact tags are just a non-hierarchical taxonomy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't have 2 groups of a singular taxonomy, so there is no way to separate post tags from each other without introducing hierarchy.

**However**, you could register a `city` taxonomy and declare that it's non-hierarchical. That's the primary difference between categories and tags. Categories have hierarchy, tags do not. Any taxonomy you register this way will have the same UI as tags.

For example, I registered a talk tag taxonomy for a CPT on my own site:

[image]

I just set `hierarchical` to `false` when I registered it.

In general, don't repurpose tags and categories for things, just register a new taxonomy, it saves a lot of trouble and makes your life easier.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the advice

Comment: If this answers your question, consider marking it as the accepted answer by clicking the large tick under the voting controls

Comment: Thanks @Tom in fact I am using WordPress Pods which has a very neat way of doing this. I definintely learned something today about flat hierarchical taxonomy...great stuff...